# OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain error and DotNetOpenAuth.dll

Tags: asp.net, openid, google-openid

I am using `DotNetOpenAuth.dll` in my website. but recently I receive this error:

> 400 error:OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain.

I know the reason of this error. My question is what is the best and quick solution for my website to solve this problem in my new domain.
I am using .net 4.5 and webform asp.net and DotNetOpenAuth.dll 4.3.0

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, after April 2014 it stopped accepting new domains for openid and oauth.  It will keep service of existing ones until April 2015.

follow [this roadmap](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration) to migrate top Google+ SignIn